# Share YouTube link in Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I wan to share `YouTube` video in `Facebook` with `UIActivityViewController`.

So i create `UIActivityViewController`:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

YouTubeAppDelegate *md = (YouTubeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

And i add the YouTube link to this.

But when i press the `Facebook` button in the `UIActivityViewController` , it post it as text in `Facebook` and not in embed video player.
Any idea how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some initial text."], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyEWkJgdftE"]];
    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
    NSArray * excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeMessage];

    UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: I want to share it from the UIActivityViewController

Comment: @MTA: can you please paste the code here for better understanding